# Keep track of ip address

Tags: java, network-programming, ip, ip-address, jpcap

I want to keep track of ip address, where have 135 destination port then in next packet with same ip address have 4445 destination port.
I try the code at below, but can't run it . 
How to solve it?

```
           packet = jpcap.getPacket();
           if(packet instanceof IPPacket){
           IPPacket ipp = (IPPacket)packet;
           InetAddress destAdd = ipp.dst_ip;
           InetAddress srcAdd = ipp.src_ip;
           if(ipp instanceof TCPPacket){
           TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)ipp;
            int destPort = tcp.dst_port;
            int srcPort = tcp.src_port;
            if(destPort == 135)
            {

                System.out.println(srcAdd + " " + destAdd + " " +srcPort + " "  + destPort);
                Packet packet2 = jpcap.getPacket();
                if(packet2 instanceof IPPacket){
                    IPPacket ipp2 = (IPPacket)packet2;
                    InetAddress destAdd2 =ipp2.dst_ip;
                    InetAddress srcAdd2 = ipp.src_ip;
                    if(destAdd2 == destAdd && srcAdd2 == srcAdd ){
                    if(ipp2 instanceof TCPPacket){
                        TCPPacket tcp2 =(TCPPacket)ipp2;
                        int destPort2 = tcp2.dst_port;
                        int srcPort2 = tcp2.src_port;
                        if(destPort2 == 4444){

                        System.out.println(srcAdd2 + " " + destAdd2 + " " +srcPort2 + " "  + destPort2);    
                        }
                     }       
                    }
                }
            }
           }
```

Comment: what happens when you try to run it? please add any error output to your question

Comment: it run the if(destPort == 135) only then stuck.

Comment: What's the question here? Can't see one.

Comment: I want to keep track ip address event where have 135 destination port then in next packet with same ip address have 4445 destination port.

Comment: I have never used jpcap, but just a question: what if you receive a packet from another "ip source" between the two you want to check?

Ps: you have written 4444 instead of 4445 in the code.

Comment: that is the problem I'm facing now. 4444 port is what I want to capture.